# Which database to use for tracking URL visits?

Tags: java, database, mysql, mongodb

I'm building a SAAS webcrawler. I would like to store information which URL was crawled by the user. I'm expecting this table to grow initially by 5-10 MB/month, later maybe up to 40 MB/month.

The DB will contain one single table:

```
user_id (INT)
url (VARCHAR)
timestamp (TIMESTAMP)
type_1 (BOOLEAN)
type_2 (BOOLEAN)
type_3 (BOOLEAN)
type_4 (BOOLEAN)
```

The data is essentially for tracking which user has crawled which url. This data will be used for payment (STRIPE/PayPal) and also for analytics.

Which database is suitable for that?

Comment: Afraid the answer is: pretty much any database will do. If you want to keep/preserve data for 1y+, *SQLite* is probably out of discussion for performance reasons – but all "real DB engines" still can cope, be it MySQL, PostgreSQL – or bigger ones like Oracle. So for recommendations, additional restrictions/requirements are needed – e.g. budget (MySQL/PostgreSQL come for free, Oracle costs a lot), should the database be shared with other projects, etc.

Comment: You are probably right - i just thought with mysql 12.5 mio rows a month will get unperformant pretty early

Comment: Ever heard of indexes and [partitions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html)? :) Requiring/wanting partitioning for performance reasons could be one of the things to add to your question's text (which again would outrule SQLite, but almost none of the other databases).

Comment: Alright. I have heard of it and i had myself a table with 100 Mio. rows. But i never partitioned one :) Will have a look into it. Ty!!

Comment: Any time! For technical questions (e.g. on partitioning), you might wish to check with [our dba sister site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/). In short: when partitioned, the DB only needs to scan those parts matching the "partition criteria"; in your case, if e.g. partitioned "by quarter of the year", you could query data from the current quarter without the DB having to scan "anything else" – which of course improves performance. You could as well easily "get rid" of old data by simply dropping the associated partition(s)  (plopp! gone), instead of running a "huge DELETE for half an hour" :)